# Why it is difficult to upgrade from 11.04 to 13.04?

Tags: upgrade

I can not update and upgrade my Ubuntu and I don't want to use another system. I want your sincere help. answers available to questions asked didn't work on my system. my version is of 11.04.

Any help would be appreciated

thanks.
regards,

Khalid Khan Seemab

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 is not supported anymore, so you should not get any updates from now on. If you want a long supported system, stick with the LTS versions (last one is 12.04). Please update your question with what you have tried to upgrade your system and which problems have you found.

Comment: I suggest you backup then do a clean install as 11.04 is no-longer supported. This will give you the cleanest system.  If you want to try upgrading take a look at this question: [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)